# add to href value of a link using jquery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, href, addition

How do i add some address to the value of the link below using jquery? like http://maps.google.com/maps?q=indianapolis

```
<div class="driving-directions-link">
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=">Get Direction</a>
</div>
```

Comment: where do you get the value from?

Comment: there is a table cell with class EventAddress and the value is coming from there and has to passed on to the url as a query string..please help me out here..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("div.driving-directions-link > a").prop("href", function (index, oldHref) {
    return oldHref + "indianapolis";
});
```

Check out `.prop`, which can take a function where `oldHref` is well, the old `href`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/c5VNK/

Comment: @AJSwift: I added an example that's working for me. Could you check it out and see what's different for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the entire URL if you'd like:
`$('a[href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q="]').attr('href', 'http://maps.google.com/maps?q=indianapolis');`

Example http://jsfiddle.net/mGVQw/